# Comparing two csv files using given columns and build a third one using specific columns from the matching lines

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, compare, match

one.csv:

```
12.23496740, -11.95760385, 3, 5, 11.1, 4
12.58295928, -11.39857395, 4, 7, 12.3, 6
12.42572572, -11.09478502, 2, 5, 12.3, 8
12.58300286, -11.95762569, 5, 11, 3.4, 7
```

two.csv:

```
12.5830, -11.3986, .2, 4
12.4257, -11.0948, .7, 3
```

I would like to match the two csv files by the 0th and 1st column and eventually output a csv file including the corresponding values from column 4 in one.csv and column 2 in two.csv like this:

three.csv

```
12.5830, -11.3986, 12.3, .2
12.4257, -11.0948, 12.3, .7
```

Comment: You have explained the problem you are trying to solve, but not shown us your code and how it doesn't work. Please edit your question to include the relevant code, and the unexpected output or error (including stack trace) that you get.

Comment: If you know that the relevant numbers in `one.csv` and `two.csv` will be the same to N decimal places, then [`round(value, N)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would read both csv files into lists of lists so that you have csv1, and csv2.  Then to loop over all of them you would do:

```
for e1 in csv1:
    for e2 in csv2:
         distance = d(e1[0],e1[1], e2[0], e2[1]) #using a function call to your distance formula
```

To save the results you might use a dictionary so that you can output later in a simple fashion.  So when saving a new entry:

```
output_dict[(e1[0], e1[1])] = [e1[3], e2[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where your problem is from the above. If you want an algorithm to use to calculate the distance based on sets of co-ordinates, feel free to use the code below:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, metric=False):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    earths_radius_km = 6378.1
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2 = map(radians, [lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlng = lng2 - lng1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlng/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = earths_radius_km * c
    if not metric:
        km_to_miles = 0.621371192
        dist = km * km_to_miles
        units = 'miles'
    else:
        dist = km
        units = 'km'
    return dist, units

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Please call from within another script'
    # example...
    lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2 = 51.0820266, 1.1834209, 52.4931226, -2.1786751
    print 'e.g. distance in km is:', haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, True)
    print 'e.g. distance in miles is:', haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
```

If I have understood correctly, you want to loop through the coordinates in one file and find the closest match in another? If this is the case just initialise the min_distance to an arbitrarily high value e.g. 1000000 for each value in the first set and then loop through the second set of coordinates call the formula above (or whatever distance function you want to use) and reset min_distance to the result if the result is < the current min_distance (and store the extra values you need from the 2nd list in a temp variable, to be over written each time you find a lower distance). Once you have gone through all iterations in the inner loop you can then store the data you need in a list before starting the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's good answer, but the solution of your problem as follows:

```
import sys
import math

def dist(point1, point2):
  return math.sqrt((point1[0]-point2[0])**2 + (point1[1]-point2[1])**2)

one = []
two = []

with open('one.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x, y, _, _, _4, _ = line.split(',')
        one.append((float(x), float(y), float(_4)))

with open('two.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x, y, _2, _ = line.split(',')
        two.append((float(x), float(y), float(_2)))

with open('three.csv', 'w') as f:
    for point in two:
        nearest = None
        distance = sys.float_info.max
        for point2 in one:
            d = dist(point2, point)
            if d < distance:
                distance = d
                nearest = point2
        f.write("%f, %f, %f, %f\n" % (point[0], point[1], nearest[2], point[2]))
```

Will produce output to three.csv:

```
12.583000, -11.398600, 12.300000, 0.200000
12.425700, -11.094800, 12.300000, 0.700000
```

If you need formatting, just do it in the last line of snippet.

Comment: nah yeah, if your points are actually geopoints you should use Haversine distance as mentioned by @ChrisProsser – replace my implementation of `dist()` function

Comment: Thanks! But, the output csv third column should read 12.3, 12.3 because those are the corresponding values to those coordinates in one.csv (4th column).

Comment: fixed! typo on the last string, should be `nearest[2]` instead of `point2[2]`

Comment: This works great on my test files, but when I try to run it on my real csv files (where one.csv is 24 columns long and two.csv is 46 columns long), I get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack.  I just changed the line split lines to include how many columns each csv had.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant solution for this problem using `numpy`:

```
def compare_files( f1name, f2name, f3name, ctc1, ctc2, columns, TOL=0.001 ):
    f1 = np.loadtxt( f1name, delimiter=',' )
    f2 = np.loadtxt( f2name, delimiter=',' )
    check = np.logical_and( *[np.absolute(s.outer(f1[:,i], f2[:,j])) < TOL for i,j in zip(ctc1,ctc2)] )
    chosen1 = f1[np.any( check, axis=1 )]
    chosen2 = f2[np.any( check, axis=0 )]
    newshape = (2,f1.shape[0],f2.shape[0])
    ind = np.indices(check.shape)[np.vstack((check,check)).reshape(newshape)]
    ind1 = ind[:len(ind)/2]
    ind2 = ind[len(ind)/2:]

    new = np.concatenate( [eval(f)[ind1, c][:,None] if f=='f1' else\
                           eval(f)[ind2, c][:,None] \
                           for f,c in columns], axis=1 )
    np.savetxt(f3name, new, delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
```

The function is general and can be applied for the case described in your question as follows:

```
f1name = 'one.csv'
f2name = 'two.csv'
f3name = 'three.csv'
ctc1 = [0,1] # columns to compare from file 1
#       ^ ^
#       | | # this arrows are just to emphisize who is compared with who...
#       v v
ctc2 = [0,1] # columns to compare from file 2
columns = [['f2',0], # file 2 column 0
           ['f2',1], # file 2 column 1
           ['f1',4], # file 1 column 4
           ['f1',2]] # file 1 column 2
TOL = 0.001
compare_files( f1name, f2name, f3name, ctc1, ctc2, columns, TOL )
```

Where `ctc1` and `ctc2` will tell the function which columns to compare (ctc). And `columns` will tell how to build the new file. In this example it is building using column 0 from `f2`, followed by column 1, then column 4 form `f1` followed by column 2.

Testing with `one.csv`:

```
12.23496740, -11.95760385, 3, 5, 11.1, 4
12.58295928, -11.39857395, 4, 7, 12.3, 6
12.42572572, -11.09478502, 2, 5, 12.3, 8
12.58300286, -11.95762569, 5, 11, 3.4, 7
```

And `two.csv`:

```
12.43, -11.0948, .7, 3
12.43, -11.0948, .7, 3
12.4257, -11.0948, .7, 3
12.43, -11.0948, .7, 3
12.5830, -11.3986, .2, 4
```

Gives a `three.csv`:

```
12.583000,-11.398600,12.300000,0.200000
12.425700,-11.094800,12.300000,0.700000
```

Comment: Thank you! So I tried applying this to my actual csv files which are 24 and 46 columns long, but I get the error "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged" on line 9.  I am not sure what to change the shape of the array to, since part of doing this is to see how many matches I get.  Is there a way to modify this code to take this into account?  Thanks!

Comment: yes, sure... the reshape was hard coded, now I've updated the answer... if the columns you want to take the values are others, you have to change the `logical_and()` and the `concatenate` commands too...

Comment: What should the logical_and() and concatenate commands be changed to?

Comment: @user2520932 Now the answer was made more general, and you can just pass the correct arguments to the function in order to compare and build the new `csv` in the way you want...

Comment: combine the numpy math with pandas for handling csv data and that should be it.